# How to use tr1 with Visual Studio 2010 (tr1::function)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, std, tr1

How does one start using the tr1 features of Visual Studio 2010? For a more specific case, I require the std::tr1::function. I tried including `#include <tr1/functional>` which reports as missing, while `#include <functional>` includes fine, but when I set this:

```
std::tr1::function<void(void)> callback;
```

I get:

```
1>d:\marmalade\projects\core\src\button.h(21): error C3083: 'tr1': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
1>d:\marmalade\projects\core\src\button.h(21): error C2039: 'function' : is not a member of '_STL'
1>d:\marmalade\projects\core\src\button.h(21): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>d:\marmalade\projects\core\src\button.h(21): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\marmalade\projects\core\src\button.h(21): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

If I use boost, it works fine, but for this project, because of using a specific framework I'd require the Visual Studio tr1 version.

As suggested, skipping the tr1, still returns the same result:

```
std::function<void(void)> callback;

1>d:\marmalade\projects\core\src\button.h(20): error C2039: 'function' : is not a member of '_STL'
1>d:\marmalade\projects\core\src\button.h(20): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>d:\marmalade\projects\core\src\button.h(20): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\marmalade\projects\core\src\button.h(20): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

Comment: `tr1` stands for [Technical Report 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1) which was a list of proposed additions to the C++ Standard. Once the proposals were accepted, the `tr1` designation became obsolete.

Comment: did you `include <functional>`?

Comment: The error says functional is not a member of _STL. Are you sure you wrote `std::function`, and not `std::functional`?

Comment: Copied the wrong error. I tried both versions, both with the same result.

Comment: @Speed : Do you have `#define std _STL` somewhere? Because that error makes no sense for the code you've shown.

Comment: No, I do not. However if I put that in, I get a completely third error saying I am redefining std.

Comment: @Speed: Works for everyone else: http://ideone.com/9gd3N, there's something missing that you haven't told us.  Especially since your compiler seems to think someone redefined `std` as a variable of type `_STL`.

Comment: It may be the library. I am using a library called Marmalade with it. It may tinker with the settings of the project...

Comment: Comment out all the includes except functional includes, and see if the errors go away on the line with the `std::function`.  If so, you know it's a header causing the problem.

Comment: @Speed If you put that macro in and get an error that you're redefining `std`, that means someone, somewhere already does `#define std`. Put `#undef std` after your includes, then find and shoot whoever defined `std` as a macro.

Comment: to help with ildjarn's guess: CTRL+SHIFT+F.  Find: "define std", Look in: "Entire Solution"

Comment: There is no matches as I do not do that in the code. I think the library http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/ is using a modified compiler...

Comment: @Speed : Did you or did you not try `#undef std`?

Comment: @Speed: Did you try commenting out various headers to see which is causing the `functional` issue?

Comment: undefining std breaks strings and vectors. Marmalade tinkers with those classes. I am sure of it...

Comment: @Speed: http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/marmalade/benefits/richer-cross-platform-native-apps says they compile with Visual C++

Comment: They do, but the Visual Studio project gets generated by their bat file.

Comment: waaaaaiiiit, Does `Marmalade` provide it's own standard library?  I think it does.  That would explain the lack of newer features, like `function`.

Comment: http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/devnet/forum/4994 I guess so.

Comment: I'll try taking the std::function files and put them directly into my source folder... Thank you for your time :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your comments, and on [this page](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/marmalade/features/open-and-standards-compliant), I think that Marmalade comes with it's own STL implementation, that appears out of date.  [This page](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/devnet/code-community) verifies that they use a version of [STLPort](http://www.stlport.org/), that does not support the TR1 that came out in 2005, much less anything newer.  Your options are:

1) Copy/write those yourself
2) Do without
3) [Download a newer version of STLPort](http://sourceforge.net/projects/stlport/).  It doesn't seem to have been updated in the last two years, so no C++11, but they do mention having `functional`, but aren't clear as to if it's in the `std` or `std::tr1` namespace.  However, this might not work with Marmalade, so make backups and be careful.

Comment: I think it's just bundled with STLPort ([source](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/devnet/code-community))... Terrible.

Comment: @Speed: Updated answer, a newer version of STLPort _may or may not help you_.

Comment: Thank you for the extended help. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Why on earth would you a library do something like that?

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2010 ships with C++11 enabled by default (or at least what is implemented). You need to use `std::function<void(void)>`.

For a complete table [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336130.aspx).

As an aside: You shouldn't use anything from TR1 nowadays. It has been integrated into the new standard.

Comment: Regardless, I still get the exact same error. `std::function<void(void)> callback;` returns the exact error, without the first one: `error C2039: 'function' : is not a member of '_STL'`

Comment: @Speed This looks highly suspicious. grep for any strange `defines`.