# C# Similarities of two arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

There **must** be an better way to do this, I'm sure...

```
// Simplified code
var a = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
var b = new List<int>() { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 };
var z = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
    if (b.Contains(a[i]))
        z.Add(a[i]);
// (z) contains all of the numbers that are in BOTH (a) and (b), i.e. { 2, 3, 5 }
```

I don't mind using the above technique, but I want something fast and efficient (I need to compare very large Lists<> multiple times), and this appears to be neither! Any thoughts?

Edit: As it makes a difference - I'm using .NET 4.0, the initial arrays are already sorted and don't contain duplicates.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649444/testing-equality-of-arrays-in-c-sharp

Comment: Similar questions: [Efficient set intersection algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497338/efficient-set-intersection-algorithm), [Fast intersection of sets: C++ vs C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060648/fast-intersection-of-sets-c-vs-c-sharp)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use IEnumerable.Intersect.

```
var z = a.Intersect(b);
```

which will *probably* be more efficient than your current solution.

note you left out one important piece of information - whether the lists happen to be ordered or not.  If they are then a couple of nested loops that pass over each input array exactly once each may be faster - and a little more fun to write.

**Edit** 
In response to your comment on ordering:

first stab at looping - it *will* need a little tweaking on your behalf but works for your initial data.

```
    int j = 0;
    foreach (var i in a)
    {
        int x = b[j];
        while (x < i)
        {
            if (x == i)
            {
                z.Add(b[j]);
            }
            j++;
            x = b[j];
        }
    }
```

this is where you need to add some unit tests ;)

**Edit**
final point - it may well be that Linq can use SortedList to perform this intersection very efficiently, if performance is a concern it is worth testing the various solutions.  Dont forget to take the sorting into account if you load your data in an un-ordered manner.

**One Final Edit** because there has been some to and fro on this and people may be using the above without properly debugging it I am posting a later version here:

```
        int j = 0;
        int b1 = b[j];
        foreach (var a1 in a)
        {
            while (b1 <= a1)
            {
                if (b1 == a1)
                    z1.Add(b[j]);
                j++;
                if (j >= b.Count)
                    break;
                b1 = b[j];
            }
        }
```

Comment: The initial arrays are ordered

Comment: Thank-you for your update, and thanks to Stack over-flow for closing the question so I *can't* post my findings ... sigh.

Comment: LIES AND SLANDER! Sorry dice, but I was not resetting the StopWatch before your code, yours is BY FAR the most efficient!

It took 15 ticks after I reset the StopWatch. Awesome.

Comment: Intersect() seems a bit weird - It takes about 2,750 ticks to "load", then no matter what dataset you throw at it on the second/third/subsequent calls it takes ~1 tick to complete.

Your method takes longer on subsequent calls (compared to Intersect), but I'd have to do a LOT of array comparisons to make using Intersect the better choice. (Using my test data, I'd have to do over 250 comparisons - not likely in my scenario - for your method to become slower over-all)

Comment: Additionally, I can halve the time your method takes by using an int[] instead of a List<int>

Comment: again interesting - note that my first implementation was seriously flawed - see the second one for improvements, also with regard to Intersect behavior see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467943/in-linq-why-are-subsequent-calls-of-ienumerable-intersect-so-much-faster

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll be watching that post to see what people say. As of now, it looks like .Intersect() doesn't actually do anything until you "query" *z*, so if we changed the code to include a .Count before the .Stop() we might get different results. I'll give that a go at work tomorrow, and post my results.

Comment: Running my tests again, with a .Count() on each test before the .Stop(), your method is 4x faster than the fastest .Intersect() (17 ticks vs 70)

Answer (score 2):

There's IEnumerable.Intersect, but since this is an extension method, I doubt it will be very efficient.

If you want efficiency, take one list and turn it into a Set, then go over the second list and see which elements are in the set. Note that I preallocate `z`, just to make sure you don't suffer from any reallocations.

```
var set = new HashSet<int>(a);
var z = new List<int>(Math.Min(set.Count, b.Count));

foreach(int i in b)
{
    if(set.Contains(i))
        a.Add(i);
}
```

This is guaranteed to run in O(N+M) (N and M being the sizes of the two lists).

Now, you could use `set.IntersectWith(b)`, and I believe it will be just as efficient, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I don't mean extension methods are inefficient by themselves, I just mean that it is only aware of the IEnumerable interface, making it hard to be efficient (unless they use a Set internally, do they?)

Answer (score 1):

The `Intersect()` method does just that. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx):

> Produces the set intersection of two sequences by using the default
>   equality comparer to compare values.

So in your case:

```
var z = a.Intersect(b);
```

Comment: Thank-you, it's soooo much easier when you know which word to put into Google!!

Answer (score 1):

If you can use LINQ, you could use the [`Enumerable.Intersect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) extension method.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`SortedSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) in `System.Collections.Generic` namespace:

```
SortedSet<int> a = new SortedSet<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
SortedSet<int> b = new SortedSet<int>() { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 };
b.IntersectWith(s2);
```

But surely you have no duplicates!
Although your second list needs not to be a `SortedSet`. It can be any collection (`IEnumerable<T>`), but internally the method act in a way that if the second list also is `SortedSet<T>`, the operation is an O(n) operation.

Comment: Why use a sorted set? Why not just a Set?

Comment: @zmbq: There is no Set<T> class in .NET Framework (Only an internal class in System.Linq.Expressions). And SortedSet<T> is the must efficient. It uses a balanced binary tree internally.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn: There is a HashSet<T> for this purpose.