# How to use Any between two ienumerables

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code inside my asp.net MVC web application:

```
var currentport = tms.TMSSwitchPorts
                     .Where(a => a.SwitchID == fromID)
                     .Select(a2 => a2.PortNumber)
                     .ToList();
            if (currentport.Any(tms.TMSSwitchPorts
                                   .Where(a => a.SwitchID == toID)
                                   .Select(a => a.PortNumber)
                                   .ToList()
                               )
               )
            {
              // do something
            }
```

but i am unable to use the `.Any()` in this way, although i am selecting the PortNumber field in both lists?

Can anyone advise?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque i want to make sure that none of the current portnumbers are already assigned to the switchID == toID

Comment: think about it: if the `SwitchID` is `fromID`, then it can't be `toID`, unless `fromID == toID`... so you just need to test that.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, no he is testing if any of the elements have `SwitchID == fromID` and `PortNumber == X`, where *some other* element has `SwitchID = toID` and `PortNumber == X` (for any X).

Comment: @jwg, perhaps... hard to guess from the current code

Comment: Think about it @ThomasLevesque

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your aim is as jwg described in his comment, you could do:

```
var currentportFrom = tms.TMSSwitchPorts
                 .Where(a => a.SwitchID == fromID)
                 .Select(a2 => a2.PortNumber)
                 .ToList();
var currentportTo = tms.TMSSwitchPorts
                 .Where(a => a.SwitchID == fromID)
                 .Select(a2 => a2.PortNumber)
                 .ToList();

if(currentportFrom.Any(cp => currentportTo.Contains(cp))
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: but in this way i will be retrieving all the records from the DB , what i was trying to do is to issue Any() on two Ienumerables so that once any conflict occur to stop the procession ...

Comment: This is a good solution. If you are really worried about efficiency, you should do `ToList` for `currentportTo`, so that that data is fetched only once and kept in memory, but *don't* do `ToList` for `currentportFrom`, so that the `Any()` stops as soon as a conflicting element is found.

Comment: @jwg I think what he wants is that each item is checked as soon as it's fetched from the database so you may not even finish enumerating the database a single time

Comment: @BenAaronson If that is possible (depending on what `tms` is), it would work by doing it as I described.

Comment: It would be even better to make `currentportTo` a `HashSet` or some other container for which we can check membership much quicker than a `List`.

Comment: @jwg But wouldn't the `ToList` on `currentportTo` necessitate loading all the data from the database once? What about not calling `ToList` on either?

Comment: @BenAaronson not calling `ToList` on either would be more optimal if the first element of `From` matches an element of `To` - because it would stop fetching `To` after that element - but worse in all other cases - because it would refetch the whole of `To` again and again for each element of `From`. I'm assuming the second case is more likely.

Comment: @jwg Really? LINQ-to-SQL doesn't optimize that?

Comment: Not unless it's a lot cleverer than I thought it was - I might well be wrong. It seems that your method with one `ToList` and @sloth's cover both the ways it could be optimized so it would be surprising if one or other was done by implicitly.

Answer (score 4):

You can to this efficiently and entirely in the database using a simple `Join`:

```
var match = tms.TMSSwitchPorts.Where(a => a.SwitchID == fromID)
                              .Join(tms.TMSSwitchPorts.Where(a => a.SwitchID == toID),
                                    (a) => a.PortNumber,
                                    (b) => b.PortNumber,
                                    (a, b) => true).Any();

if (match) { ... }
```

---

The generated SQL should look like

```
SELECT 
    (CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS(
            SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
            FROM [TMSSwitchPorts] AS [t0]
            INNER JOIN [TMSSwitchPorts] AS [t1] ON [t0].[PortNumber] = [t1].[PortNumber]
            WHERE ([t0].[SwitchID] = @p0) AND ([t1].[SwitchID] = @p1)
            ) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
     END) AS [value]
```

so you don't have any data expect a single `1` or `0` moving over the wire and you don't have to clutter up your application memory.

---

The code

```
if (currentport.Any(tms.TMSSwitchPorts
                               .Where(a => a.SwitchID == toID)
                               .Select(a => a.PortNumber)
                               .ToList()
                           )
```

will not work because `Any` expects a predicate in the form of `Func<T, bool>`, but you pass it a `List<Int>` (assuming `PortNumber` is an `int`).

Comment: +1 This is the best solution if `tms` is a database query and not some other source. Don't want to edit in order to impose my style but I would love it if you moved the `Any()` to its own line :)

Comment: Yep, it wasn't made clear in the question that this was linq-to-sql (or -entities) or that minimizing data transfer from the db was an aim. With those things in mind, this is probably the preferred solution

Comment: @BenAaronson Well, the question is tagged `entity-framework` :-)

Comment: @sloth Heh, well spotted

Answer (score 1):

Take the analogous list for `SwitchID == toID`.

```
var alreadyUsed = tms.TMSSwitchPorts
                     .Where(a => a.SwitchID == toID)
                     .Select(a2 => a2.PortNumber)
                     .ToList();
```

Then just check that nothing appears in both two lists.

```
if (currentPort.Intersect(alreadyUsed).Any())
{ // do something }
```

### Explanation:

`Any()` doesn't work the way you think it does. By itself as used above, it checks for any elements in the container. As shown in @BenAaronson's answer (which is slightly better than this answer), it checks if an `IEnumerable` contains any element which for which the function argument returns true.

```
list1.Any(HasSomeProperty)
```

where `HasSomeProperty` is a function which takes an element of `list1` and returns a bool; or more usually with a lambda:

```
list1.Any(x => SomePropertyHoldsFor(x))
```

### Edit:

I said @BenAaronson's answer was better because it allows some 'short-circuiting' optimizations that I didn't think my solution had. These are mentioned in the comments to his answer. However, with some trial and error I found that Intersect does automatically make the same optimizations - specifically it caches the 'output' of one IEnumerable for comparison with each element of the other, rather than traverse it each time. So my solution is better, as `Intersect` does automatically what you have to think about a little bit for Ben's method ;) @sloth's answer involves a different automatic optimization, and is much is better for the database query using `Queryable` that the asker had in mind.

[This answer explains how `Intersect` works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9468084/1737957) - it is not really 'caching', but it only accesses each `IEnumerable` once.

Answer (score 1):

Based on jwg's comment, you can check to see if there is a match between the first set of ports (From) and the second set (to), using a `Contains` match:

```
var fromPorts = tms.TMSSwitchPorts
                 .Where(a => a.SwitchID == fromID)
                 .Select(a2 => a2.PortNumber);

if (tms.TMSSwitchPorts
       .Any(a => a.SwitchID == toID && 
                 fromPorts.Contains(a.PortNumber)))
```